# Bash using --- (triple dash) at start of format string for printf

Tags: bash

I have a stored string "`--- RE%d ---\n`" in a format variable for `printf`, but when I use it like:

```
format="--- RE%d ---\n"
printf $format 1
```

`printf` treats `--` like I want to use some option. When I put anything before `---`, it works fine. Is there a way to make `printf` to print just: `--- RE1 ---`? I was using `\r` as 1st character, but it is shown at script output as ^H.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add `--`:

```
format="--- RE%d ---\n"
printf -- "$format" 1
```

---

Use `--` to signify the end of the options.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `printf -- "$format" 1`?  Or does Bash manage to treat it as a built-in command with special handling for string arguments?